# Stanford NER won't use my training file, instead uses it's default

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, training-data

I'm trying to train the Stanford NER classifier to identify specific things in text data bases.I have made a new .prop file and a training file, and I get results, but they are the default results that I would get if I just ran the classifier without training. Anything I can do to fit this?

**This is my code:**

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;public class NLP_train {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       Properties props = StringUtils.propFileToProperties("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/trainingfile.prop");

       StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);


       // read some text in the text variable
       File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/target.txt");
       // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
       Annotation document = new Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(inputFile));

       // run all Annotators on this text
       pipeline.annotate(document);

       List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

       for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
           // traversing the words in the current sentence
           // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
           for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
               // this is the text of the token
               String word = token.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class);
               // this is the POS tag of the token
               String pos = token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
               // this is the NER label of the token
               String ne = token.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);






               System.out.println(String.format("Print: word: [%s] pos: [%s] ne: [%s]", word, pos, ne));
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**Here is my .prop file:**

> trainFile = C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/trainingfile.tsv
>
> serializeTo = C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/ner-model.ser.gz
>
> map = word=0,answer=1
>
> useClassFeature=true
>
> useWord=true
>
> useNGrams=true
>
> noMidNGrams=true
>
> useDisjunctive=true
>
> maxNGramLeng=6
>
> usePrev=true
>
> useNext=true
>
> useSequences=true
>
> usePrevSequences=true
>
> maxLeft=1
>
> the next 4 deal with word shape features
>
> useTypeSeqs=true
>
> useTypeSeqs2=true
>
> useTypeySequences=true
>
> wordShape=chris2useLC

**And an excerpt of my training file:**

> The      0
>
> Type     Radar
>
> 347G     Radar
>
> ``       0
>
> Rice     0
>
> Bowl     0
>
> ''       0

Answer (score 0):

To train a new NER model, you need to train it directly using the `edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier` class. You cannot train new models within CoreNLP. Also, while both use properties files, the files are different in that a properties file for an NER run directly gives properties to the CRFClassifier class while a CoreNLP properties file can give properties to all sorts of things. as a result, property names are placed into their own namespaces, and so a property for use by NER would have a name like: `ner.model`.

So, what you have to do is first train a new NER model using CRFClassifier, using roughly the data and properties file you show. That will give you a serialized NER model file. The CRF FAQ has [some instructions](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a). Then you need to make a properties file for CoreNLP that specifies for NER to run the new model. For example if your new model is `/Users/manning/ner/brands.crf.ser.gz` then you might use the property:

`ner.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,/Users/manning/ner/brands.crf.ser.gz`